# Spark LinearRegressionSummary "normal" summary

Tags: apache-spark-mllib

According to [LinearRegressionSummary (Spark 2.1.0 JavaDoc)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/LinearRegressionSummary.html#pValues()), p-values are only available for the "normal" solver.

> This value is only available when using the "normal" solver.

What the hell is the "normal" solver?

I'm doing this:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineModel} 
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator 
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler 
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegressionModel 
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{CrossValidator, CrossValidatorModel, ParamGridBuilder} 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
    .
    .
    .
val (trainingData, testData): (DataFrame, DataFrame) = 
  com.acme.pta.accuracy.Util.splitData(output, testProportion)
    .
    .
    .
val lr = 
  new org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression()
  .setSolver("normal").setMaxIter(maxIter)

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(lr))

val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
  .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, Array(0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9))
  .addGrid(lr.regParam, Array(0,6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.01))
  .build()

val cv = new CrossValidator()
  .setEstimator(pipeline)
  .setEvaluator(evaluator)
  .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
  .setNumFolds(numFolds) // Use 3+ in practice

val cvModel: CrossValidatorModel = cv.fit(trainingData)

val pipelineModel: PipelineModel = cvModel.bestModel.asInstanceOf[PipelineModel]
val lrModel: LinearRegressionModel = 
  pipelineModel.stages(0).asInstanceOf[LinearRegressionModel]

val modelSummary = lrModel.summary
Holder.log.info("lrModel.summary: " + modelSummary)
try {
  Holder.log.info("feature p values: ")
  // Exception occurs on line below.
  val featuresAndPValues = features.zip(lrModel.summary.pValues)
  featuresAndPValues.foreach(
    (featureAndPValue: (String, Double)) => 
    Holder.log.info(
      "feature: " + featureAndPValue._1 + ": " + featureAndPValue._2))
} catch {
  case _: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException 
            => Holder.log.error("Cannot compute p-values")
}
```

I am still getting the `UnsupportedOperationException`.

The exception message is:

> No p-value available for this LinearRegressionModel

Is there something else I need to be doing?  I'm using

```
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.1"
```

Is pValues supported in that version?

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix this issue? I have the same problem but for coefficient standard errors. I did set solver to "normal" and "elasticNetParam = 0" but issue persists.

Comment: If I did, the solution is below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Updated**

## **tl;dr**

### Solution 1

In normal `LinearRegression` pValues and other "normal" statistics are only present when one of the parameters `elasticNetParam` or `regParam` is zero. So you can change

```
.addGrid( lr.elasticNetParam, Array( 0.0 ) )
```

or

```
.addGrid( lr.regParam, Array( 0.0 ) )
```

### Solution 2

Make custom version of `LinearRegression` which would explicitly use

1. "normal" solver for regression.
2. `Cholesky` solver for `WeightedLeastSquares`.

I made this class as an extension to `ml.regression` package.

```
package org.apache.spark.ml.regression

import scala.collection.mutable

import org.apache.spark.SparkException
import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Instance
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.ml.optim.WeightedLeastSquares
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.{Param, ParamMap, ParamValidators}
import org.apache.spark.ml.util._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorImplicits._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, Row}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

class CholeskyLinearRegression ( override val uid: String )
    extends Regressor[ Vector, CholeskyLinearRegression, LinearRegressionModel ]
    with LinearRegressionParams with DefaultParamsWritable with Logging {

    import CholeskyLinearRegression._

    def this() = this(Identifiable.randomUID("linReg"))

    def setRegParam(value: Double): this.type = set(regParam, value)
    setDefault(regParam -> 0.0)

    def setFitIntercept(value: Boolean): this.type = set(fitIntercept, value)
    setDefault(fitIntercept -> true)

    def setStandardization(value: Boolean): this.type = set(standardization, value)
    setDefault(standardization -> true)

    def setElasticNetParam(value: Double): this.type = set(elasticNetParam, value)
    setDefault(elasticNetParam -> 0.0)

    def setMaxIter(value: Int): this.type = set(maxIter, value)
    setDefault(maxIter -> 100)

    def setTol(value: Double): this.type = set(tol, value)
    setDefault(tol -> 1E-6)

    def setWeightCol(value: String): this.type = set(weightCol, value)

    def setSolver(value: String): this.type = set(solver, value)
    setDefault(solver -> Auto)

    def setAggregationDepth(value: Int): this.type = set(aggregationDepth, value)
    setDefault(aggregationDepth -> 2)

    override protected def train(dataset: Dataset[_]): LinearRegressionModel = {

        // Extract the number of features before deciding optimization solver.
        val numFeatures = dataset.select(col($(featuresCol))).first().getAs[Vector](0).size
        val w = if (!isDefined(weightCol) || $(weightCol).isEmpty) lit(1.0) else col($(weightCol))

        val instances: RDD[Instance] = 
            dataset
            .select( col( $(labelCol) ), w, col( $(featuresCol) ) )
            .rdd.map {
                case Row(label: Double, weight: Double, features: Vector) =>
                Instance(label, weight, features)
            }

        // if (($(solver) == Auto &&
        //   numFeatures <= WeightedLeastSquares.MAX_NUM_FEATURES) || $(solver) == Normal) {
        // For low dimensional data, WeightedLeastSquares is more efficient since the
        // training algorithm only requires one pass through the data. (SPARK-10668)

        val optimizer = new WeightedLeastSquares( 
            $(fitIntercept), 
            $(regParam),
            elasticNetParam = $(elasticNetParam), 
            $(standardization), 
            true,
            solverType = WeightedLeastSquares.Cholesky, 
            maxIter = $(maxIter), 
            tol = $(tol)
        )

        val model = optimizer.fit(instances)

        val lrModel = copyValues(new LinearRegressionModel(uid, model.coefficients, model.intercept))
        val (summaryModel, predictionColName) = lrModel.findSummaryModelAndPredictionCol()

        val trainingSummary = new LinearRegressionTrainingSummary(
            summaryModel.transform(dataset),
            predictionColName,
            $(labelCol),
            $(featuresCol),
            summaryModel,
            model.diagInvAtWA.toArray,
            model.objectiveHistory
        )

        lrModel
        .setSummary( Some( trainingSummary ) )

        lrModel
    }

    override def copy(extra: ParamMap): CholeskyLinearRegression = defaultCopy(extra)
}

object CholeskyLinearRegression 
    extends DefaultParamsReadable[CholeskyLinearRegression] {

    override def load(path: String): CholeskyLinearRegression = super.load(path)

    val MAX_FEATURES_FOR_NORMAL_SOLVER: Int = WeightedLeastSquares.MAX_NUM_FEATURES

    /** String name for "auto". */
    private[regression] val Auto = "auto"

    /** String name for "normal". */
    private[regression] val Normal = "normal"

    /** String name for "l-bfgs". */
    private[regression] val LBFGS = "l-bfgs"

    /** Set of solvers that LinearRegression supports. */
    private[regression] val supportedSolvers = Array(Auto, Normal, LBFGS)
}
```

All you have to do is to paste it to the separate file in the project and change `LinearRegression`  to `CholeskyLinearRegression` in your code.

```
val lr = new CholeskyLinearRegression() // new LinearRegression()
        .setSolver( "normal" )
        .setMaxIter( maxIter )
```

**It works with non-zero params and gives pValues**. Tested on following params grid.

```
val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
        .addGrid( lr.elasticNetParam, Array( 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9 ) )
        .addGrid( lr.regParam, Array( 0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.01 ) )
        .build()
```

## Full investigation

I initially thought that the main issue is with the model being not fully preserved. Trained model is not preserved after fitting in `CrossValidator`. It is understandable because of memory consumption. There is an ongoing [debate](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/18313/files) on how should it be resolved. [Issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21087) in JIRA.

You can see in the commented section that I tried to extract parameters from the best model in order to run it again. Then I found out that the model summary is ok, it's just for some parameters `diagInvAtWa` has length of 1 and basically a zero.

For ridge regression or Tikhonov regularization (`elasticNet = 0`) and any `regParam` pValues and other "normal" statistics can be computed but for Lasso method and something in between (elastic net) not. Same goes for `regParam = 0`: with any `elasticNet` pValues were computed.

**Why is that**

`LinearRegression` [uses](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/561505e2fc290fc2cee3b8464ec49df773dca5eb/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/LinearRegression.scala#L227) Weighted Least Square optimizer for "normal" solver with `solverType = WeightedLeastSquares.Auto`. This optimizer has [two options](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/561505e2fc290fc2cee3b8464ec49df773dca5eb/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/optim/WeightedLeastSquares.scala#L229) for solvers: `QuasiNewton` or `Cholesky`. The former is selected only when both `regParam` and `elasticNetParam` are non-zeroes.

```
val solver = if (
    ( solverType == WeightedLeastSquares.Auto && 
        elasticNetParam != 0.0 && 
        regParam != 0.0 ) ||
    ( solverType == WeightedLeastSquares.QuasiNewton ) ) {

    ...
    new QuasiNewtonSolver(fitIntercept, maxIter, tol, effectiveL1RegFun)
} else {
    new CholeskySolver
}
```

So in your parameters grid the `QuasiNewtonSolver` will be always used because there are no combinations of `regParam` and `elasticNetParam` where one of them is zero.

We know that in order to get pValues and other "normal" statistics such as t-statistic or std. error of coefficients the diagonal of matrix (A^T * W * A)^-1 (`diagInvAtWA`) must not be a vector with only one zero. This condition is set in definition of [pValues](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/561505e2fc290fc2cee3b8464ec49df773dca5eb/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/LinearRegression.scala#L822).

`diagInvAtWA` is a vector of diagonal elements of packed upper triangular matrix (`solution.aaInv`).

```
val diagInvAtWA = solution.aaInv.map { inv => ...
```

For `Cholesky solver` it is [calculated](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f3137feecd30c74c47dbddb0e22b4ddf8cf2f912/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/optim/NormalEquationSolver.scala#L71) but for `QuasiNewton` [not](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f3137feecd30c74c47dbddb0e22b4ddf8cf2f912/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/optim/NormalEquationSolver.scala#L113). Second [parameter](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f3137feecd30c74c47dbddb0e22b4ddf8cf2f912/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/optim/NormalEquationSolver.scala#L37) for `NormalEquationSolution` is this matrix.

You technically could make your own version of LinearRegression with

## Reproduction

In this example I used data `sample_linear_regression_data.txt` from [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/sample_linear_regression_data.txt).

Full code of reproduction

```
import org.apache.spark._

import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineModel} 
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.{RegressionEvaluator, BinaryClassificationEvaluator}
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler 
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.{LinearRegressionModel, LinearRegression}
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{CrossValidator, CrossValidatorModel, ParamGridBuilder} 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap

object Main {

    def main( args: Array[ String ] ): Unit = {

        val spark =
            SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName( "SO" )
            .master( "local[*]" )
            .config( "spark.driver.host", "localhost" )
            .getOrCreate()

        import spark.implicits._

        val data = 
            spark
            .read
            .format( "libsvm" )
            .load( "./sample_linear_regression_data.txt" )

        val Array( training, test ) = 
            data
            .randomSplit( Array( 0.9, 0.1 ), seed = 12345 )

        val maxIter = 10;

        val lr = new LinearRegression()
            .setSolver( "normal" )
            .setMaxIter( maxIter )

        val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
            // .addGrid( lr.elasticNetParam, Array( 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9 ) )
            .addGrid( lr.elasticNetParam, Array( 0.0 ) )
            .addGrid( lr.regParam, Array( 0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.01 ) )
            .build()

        val pipeline = new Pipeline()
            .setStages( Array( lr ) )

        val cv = new CrossValidator()
            .setEstimator( pipeline )
            .setEvaluator( new RegressionEvaluator )
            .setEstimatorParamMaps( paramGrid )
            .setNumFolds( 2 )  // Use 3+ in practice

        val cvModel = 
            cv
            .fit( training )

        val pipelineModel: PipelineModel = 
            cvModel
            .bestModel
            .asInstanceOf[ PipelineModel ]

        val lrModel: LinearRegressionModel = 
            pipelineModel
            .stages( 0 )
            .asInstanceOf[ LinearRegressionModel ]

        // Technically there is a way to use exact ParamMap
        // to build a new LR but for the simplicity I'll 
        // get and set them explicitly

        // lrModel.params.foreach( ( param ) => {

        //     println( param )
        // } )

        // val bestLr = new LinearRegression()
        //     .setSolver( "normal" )
        //     .setMaxIter( maxIter )
        //     .setRegParam( lrModel.getRegParam )
        //     .setElasticNetParam( lrModel.getElasticNetParam )

        // val bestLrModel = bestLr.fit( training )

        val modelSummary = 
            lrModel
            .summary

        println( "lrModel pValues: " + modelSummary.pValues.mkString( ", " ) )

        spark.stop()
    }
}
```

**Original**

There are three solver algorithms [available](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/655f6f86f84ff5241d1d20766e1ef83bb32ca5e0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/LinearRegression.scala#L182):

- `l-bfgs` - Limited-memory Broyden–Fletcher–Goldfarb–Shanno algorithm which is a limited-memory quasi-Newton optimization [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS).
- `normal` - using [Normal Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)) as an analytical solution to the linear regression problem.  It is basically a [weighted least squares approach](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/optim/WeightedLeastSquares.scala) or [reweighted least squares approach](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/optim/IterativelyReweightedLeastSquares.scala).
- `auto` - solver algorithm is selected automatically. The Normal Equations solver will be used when possible, but this will automatically fall back to iterative optimization methods when needed

The `coefficientStandardErrors`, `tValues` and `pValues` are only available when using the "normal" solver because they are all based on `diagInvAtWA` - a diagonal of matrix (A^T * W * A)^-1.

Comment: I'm doing this:     val lr = new org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression()
      .setMaxIter(maxIter).setSolver("normal")
Is there something else I need to be doing?

Comment: I assume you already have data in proper format so yeah just fit it in and see the results. I updated the answer.

Comment: The data is a DataFrame.  Is that sufficient?

Comment: `ml.regression.LinearRegression()` uses `Dataframe`, `CrossValidator().fit( ... )` requires `Dataset` format. Maybe there is a internal conversion, I don't know. At what operation you get `UnsupportedOperationException` and what the details about that exception? It usually prints additional information.

Comment: This is the message given by the exception: "No p-value available for this LinearRegressionModel".

Comment: Updated. It was actually more math related than code related.

Comment: Updated again. I would assume that developers had a good reason to use QuasiNewton for non-zero parameters.

Comment: @PaulReiners I tried to replicate `LinearRegression` using only normal solver and Cholesky decomposition. Resulting `CholeskyLinearRegression` worked and gave pValues for non-zero params.

Comment: @PaulReiners So, was it helpful?

Comment: I am having this issue, but in pyspark. Even though I set ``solver='normal'`` and ``regParam=0`` I still get "No Std. Error of coefficients available for this LinearRegressionModel."  Is there a way to make a Cholesky solver work in pyspark?

Comment: I have the same issue. Even though I set solver='normal' and regParam=0 I still get "No Std. Error of coefficients available for this LinearRegressionModel."