# Get the stardard error from linear regression model in pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, linear-regression

I have the following code to perform a linear regression on pySpark:

```
lr = LinearRegression(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol='units_sold', maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)
lr_model = lr.fit(premodel_df)
summary =lr_model.summary
```

I am trying to get the standard error from the coefficients, which is supposed to be done with:

```
summary.coefficientStandardErrors
```

But I obtain the folloging error:

> An error occurred while calling o704.coefficientStandardErrors. :
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Std. Error of coefficients
> available for this LinearRegressionModel

Is there another way to obtain the standard error?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegressionTrainingSummary.html#pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegressionTrainingSummary.coefficientStandardErrors) the `coefficientStandardErrors` are only available when when using the “normal” solver, however the relevant [scala code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5103e00c4ce5fcc4264ca9c4df12295d42557af6/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/LinearRegression.scala#L1018) shows a different condition.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46696867/2129801) suggests to set either `elasticNetParam` or `regParam` to zero. This worked for me.